# How to keep the "ORTHO" mode always active in autoCAD

Tags: .net, autocad

In Autocad to activate the "ORTHO" mode I do this:

```
Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database.Orthomode = True
```

But how can I prevent the "ORTHO" mode from being deactivated during the execution of a command I made in VB.NET?
Thanks a lot, bye.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ready and working sample to share, but You can do it using mechanism called reactors.
Create reactor triggered when system variable changed, and check if active command is one of yours commands.